# What's going on in here? Python for loop with multiple in's

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to loop over two lists at the same time, not realizing that too much of a hassle when they're not the same size.

However, while fiddling around in IDLE, I found this really weird output.

This is Python 3.3.2

```
>>> for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]:
        print(i, j)


[1, 2, 3] 5
True 5
```

Few things about this, the True becomes False sometimes, as seen below:

```
for i in [77,2,3], j in [588,7,6]:
    print(i, j)

[77, 2, 3] 5
False 5
```

And the 5 always stays a 5.

This works for two in statements, but with three statements it gives me this:

```
>>> for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6], k in [7,8,9]:
        print(i, j, k)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6], k in [7,8,9]:
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

To me, this looks very weird.

What's the 5? Where does the True/False come from? And why does this behave so.. not-pythonic? You'd expect the first code to print:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Edit: I did indeed have j=5 earlier in the script, in a valid for loop.

Second edit: I was not actually looking for `for i, j in zip(list1, list2)`

I was trying to shorten my code by replacing two for loops with one, but later I realized that that's a bad idea for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must've defined `j=5` in your program that's why you're getting 5 as output, otherwise your program is going to raise NameError.

```
>>> for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]:
            print(i, j)
...     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-b8d5b59be30b>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]:
NameError: name 'j' is not defined

>>> j = 5
>>> for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]:
            print(i, j)
...     
[1, 2, 3] 5
True 5
```

The above loop is **equivalent** to these two:

```
>>> for i in ([1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]):
            print(i, j)
...     
[1, 2, 3] 5
True 5
>>> for i in ([1,2,3], True):
            print(i, j)
...     
[1, 2, 3] 5
True 5
```

Note that a variable used in a for-loop automatically gets assigned to the last value after the end of the loop, but only in normal loops(In Python 2.x this used to happen with List comprehensions as well).:

```
>>> for m in range(5):
    print (m, end=' ')
...     
0 1 2 3 4
>>> m
4
```

---

To get the expected output use `zip`:

```
>>> for x, y in zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]):
...     print (x, y)
...     
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: You should *also* mention `zip()` to produce the expected outcome.

Answer (score 5):

`for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]:` is being parsed as `for i in ([1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]):`, where the first `in` is part of the `for ... in` construct and the second `in` is the membership test operator.  Apparently, some code that was previously executed set `j` to 5 and left it that way, and so since `j=5` is in `[4,5,6]`, this becomes `for i in ([1,2,3], True):`.  Python then iterates over this two-element sequence, setting `i` to first `[1,2,3]` and then `True`, and leaving `j` alone.  In the three-statement version, a similar parse occurs, but as `k` has not been assigned a value prior to the loop, it results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

`j` equals to `5`
so

```
for i in [1,2,3], j in [4,5,6]:
        print(i, j)
```

means

```
for (i in [1,2,3], (j in [4,5,6])):
        print(i, j)
```

`i` changes from `[1,2,3]` to result of `(j in [4,5,6])`
`j` is always `5`

and you get

```
[1, 2, 3] 5  -> i = [1, 2, 3],      j = 5
True 5       -> i = (j in [4,5,6]), j = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what you want is

```
for (i, j) in zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]):
    print (i, j)
```